# как scrollbar сделать disabled

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Понимаю что вопрос, казало бы прост, но.. Мне необходимо прекратить активность скроллбара при определенном событии. Не скрыть (overflow: hidden), а наоборот оставить его, но сделать disabled. У кого какие варианты? Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  window.scrollTo(e.pageXoffset, e.pageYoffset);
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, а как выглядит способ обратного эффекта?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov, что значит "обратного эффекта"?

Comment: сделать enabled

Comment: вызываете эту функцию только тогда, когда нужно заблокировать, в ином случае не блокируете

Comment: все не так просто. У меня два события, в одном из которых я блокирую скроллбар, а в другом событии напротив, делаю активным.

Comment: передавайте флаг, по нему ориентируйтесь, если `true`, то исполняйте `window.scrol...`, если же нет, то ничего не делайте

Comment: ок, попробую, спасибо